# How to update an item in Recyclerview without reloading the image in Android

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, download, reload

In a Recyclerview, there are a number of items that have an image. The user wants to download the desired images, but when the desired item must be updated to show the downloaded percentage, the problem is that when the desired percentage It shows the user that he wants to reload the photo, but I just want the `Progress` field to be updated.

Like the image below, the user clicks on the image to download it, but when the download percentage is edited, the image is constantly reloaded, but what I want is to load the image once and edit only `Progress`, such as downloading images in **Telegram** and **Whatsapp**.
[image]

**in adapter:**

```
public class AdpNotice extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdpNotice.ViewHolder> {

private List<Notice> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();

public AdpNotice() {
    
}

public void AddItem(Notice item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void SetProgressMessage(double messageId, int progress) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Notice item : ITEMS) {
        if (item.MessageId == messageId) {
            item.Progress = progress;
            item.DownloadStatus = "Downloading";
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    notifyItemChanged(i, "CHANGE_PROGRESS");
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(AppController.Context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_notice_image, viewGroup, false);
           
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewNotice, int i) {
    Notice item = GetItem(i);

    
            switch (item.DownloadStatus) {
                case "Downloaded":
                    
                    viewNotice.tvDownloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewNotice.tvTotalSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    AppController.SetPicFile(viewNotice.imgRow,
                            new File(item.DirectoryPath + item.FileName)
                            , "");
                    
                    break;
                case "Downloading":
                    
                    viewNotice.tvTotalSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewNotice.tvDownloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    
                    viewNotice.tvDownloading.setText(item.Progress + "%");
                    break;
                case "NotDownloaded":
                    
                    viewNotice.tvDownloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewNotice.tvTotalSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    AppController.SetPicUrl(viewNotice.imgRow, item.FilePath, 0, "");
                    break;
            }
            viewNotice.tvTotalSize.setText(item.FileSize);
            viewNotice.tvDate.setText(item.Date);
            AppController.SetPicDrawable(viewNotice.imgDownload, R.drawable.download_file, "");
            
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Object payLoad : payloads) {
        if (payLoad.equals("CHANGE_PROGRESS")) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    } else {
        onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ITEMS.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tvDate)
    TextView tvDate;
    @BindView(R.id.tvText)
    @Nullable
    TextView tvText;
    @BindView(R.id.imgRow)
    @Nullable
    ImageView imgRow;

    //ImageLayout
    @BindView(R.id.tvTotalSize)
    @Nullable
    TextView tvTotalSize;
    @BindView(R.id.imgDownload)
    @Nullable
    ImageView imgDownload;
    @BindView(R.id.tvDownloading)
    @Nullable
    TextView tvDownloading;
    @BindView(R.id.layoutLoading)
    @Nullable
    RelativeLayout layoutLoading;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
}
```

**To change Progress in Activity, I just call this method:**

```
AdpNotice.SetProgressMessage(messageId , progress);
```

Comment: Due to Arabic language I am unable to understand your screenshots.

Comment: This language is **Persian**, not Arabic.In principle, the problem is on **reloading images**, and the numbers written in Persian are not a problem.Which is fully explained . post updated please see again.@MuhammadFarhanArif

Answer (score 1):

In the method `SetProgressMessage`, you should use `notifyItemChanged` API with a payload.

```java
// use notifyItemChanged with payload
public void SetProgressMessage(double messageId, int progress) {
    int i = 0;
    ...
    notifyItemChanged(i, "PROGRESS");
}

// override onBindViewHolder with payloads parameters
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, 
        @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(payload in playloads) {
        if(payload == "PROGRESS"){
            found = true
            // just update progress 
        }
    }
    if(found) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    }
}
```

Comment: That means I do not use this method 
**@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewNotice, int i)**

Comment: @MohammadSalmanian You need to override both `onBindViewHolder` methods, the method without payloads to fill all of the views in the item view. the method with payloads to just update some partial views in the item view.

Comment: @MohammadSalmanian You need to really understand the two API.

Comment: did not work. update post. please see again.